# Selenium WebDriver узнать был ли закрыт браузер?

Tags: selenium

Мне нужно узнать был ли вызван метод IWebDriver.Quit() на определенном объекте. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно через логирование, если просто хотите узнать. Если получится, то добавить логирование в метод, что бы при вызове писал что то в лог файл или консоль, или настроить логер. 
[Про настройку логирования](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/log4j2-appenders-layouts-filters)

Можно тестик написать на проверку что этот метод был вызван, это можно сделать с помощью Mockito.
К примеру:

```
verify(mockedList, times(0)).add("never happened"); 
verify(mockedList, never()).add("never happened");
```

[Mockito.verify](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)